# Correct computation of Fisher Information

Tags: fisher-information

Let $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ be an i.i.d sample from the parametric family of distributions $\mathcal{P} = \{P_\theta: \theta \in \Theta \}$ ($X_i \sim P_{\theta_0}$ are i.i.d. random variables, $\theta_0 \in \Theta$ is a fixed true parameter).

I am studying statistics and trying to understand the following formula for Fisher information:

$$I(\theta) = \mathrm{E}_\theta\left[ \left(\frac{\partial \log f(X_1; \theta)}{\partial \theta} \right)^2 \right]$$

I see the following algorithm for computing $I(\theta)$:

1. Using that $X_1 \sim P_{\theta_0}$ we compute the quantity $g(X_1; \theta) = \left(\frac{\partial \log f(X_1; \theta)}{\partial \theta} \right)^2$. Since $\theta_0$ is fixed, we can say that $X_1$ doesn't depend on $\theta$ and the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ is easily computed (at this stage we can even treat $X_1$ as some fixed constant).
2. After that we need to assume that $X_1 \sim P_{\theta}$ and compute the expected value $\mathrm{E}_\theta[g(X_1; \theta)]$.

**My question is the following: is this algorithm correct?**

I am concerned about the non-trivial fact of "changing" $X_1$ distribution from $P_{\theta_0}$ to $P_{\theta}$ at the second stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer.
There are 2 mistakes in the post above.

1) Our statistical model is $X_1 \sim P_\theta$ where $\theta \in \Theta$, not $X_1 \sim P_{\theta_0}$. We don't know the true value of the parameter. So there is no "change" of distribution.
2) $X_1(\omega)$ as function of outcomes $\omega$ doesn't depend on parameter $\theta$. Indeed, every random variable is just a measurable function that maps $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (by definition). Only the distribution $P_\theta$ of $X_1(\omega)$ depends on $\theta$ but not $X_1(\omega)$ itself. Hence $\frac{d X_1(\omega)}{d \theta} = 0$.